# Enlarge outer margin over two pages on twosided document

Tags: margins, changepage, adjustwidth

I am quite happy with `adjustwidth*` to enlarge the outer margin in a twosided LaTeX document. My problem is, that it doesn't seem to work if the environment is spread over two pages.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{12cm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-20mm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Here the text is extended into the right margin on the second page, although it is the inner margin.
[image: the <code>adjustwidth</code> doesn't work over two pages]

Is there a better package or a workaround for that, so the text on the next page is shifted to the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I don't think that you can do this automatically. TeX typesets paragraph by paragraph. It is only after a paragraph is set does TeX check if there should have been a pagebreak in the middle of it. If so TeX breaks the page, puts the remainder of the typeset paragraph at the top of the next page, and then carries on with the next paragraph. This means that you can have only one setting of a paragraph. If you need to change paragraph margins at a pagebreak you really have to do it manually by splitting the paragraph into two where the last word on the first page occurs and starting a new non-indented paragraph with the first word on the second page.